toggle visibility of 2 divs with 2 buttons independently
I'm new in coding and I'm having trouble with this one:
I create two divs (audiodescription-text and options-wrapper). I want to toggle their visibility independently. In other words, the visibility of one div doesn't affect another one's visibility. That's why I created 2 buttons, one for each div.

Is all this code really necessary just to ask about toggling visibility?

A variable can only have one value. You're using the same variable div for both audiodescription-text and options-wrapper. Use different variables. Also, use better names for the variables, div is too generic.

Too much code, Pls post only a minimal reproducible example. You can place all your javascript enclosed in one script tag . Also use different name for var div  ex const audio = document.getElementById('audiodescription-text') and const wrapper = document.getElementById('options-wrapper'). You can also then use a class (ex with display none) that you will toggle with JS toggle() function

And the same thing for the display variables. You should also use true/false rather than 1/0 for boolean values.

In your original code you have these functions in separate <script> tags. Script tags don't have their own scope, they share all their global variables.

@juliopanz Mehdi's comment says exactly what to change. Use const audio for one of the divs, and const wrapper for the other div. Then use those variables in the corresponding showHideXxx() functions.

You're using the save variables div and display for both buttons. You need to use different variables for them in the two functions.


var audio_div = document.getElementById('audiodescription-text');
var audio_display = true;

function showHidenButtonAudiodescription() {
  if (!audio_display) {
    audio_div.style.display = 'none';
    audio_display = true;
    document.querySelector("button_audiodescription").innerHTML = "Exibir audiodescrição";
  } else {
    audio_div.style.display = 'inherit';
    audio_display = false;
    document.querySelector("button_audiodescription").innerHTML = "Ocultar audiodescrição";
  }
}

/* Inserir aqui script para exibir ou ocultar o menu de seleção de cores */
var options_div = document.getElementById('options-wrapper');
var options_display = true;

function showHidenButtonModel() {
  if (!options_display) {
    options_div.style.display = 'none';
    options_display = 1;
    document.querySelector("button_model").innerHTML = "Exibir audiodescrição";
  } else {
    options_div.style.display = 'inherit';
    options_display = false;
    document.querySelector("button_model").innerHTML = "Ocultar audiodescrição";
  }
}
<div id="audiodescription-instructions">
  <button_audiodescription id="button_audiodescription" onclick="showHidenButtonAudiodescription()">Exibir audiodescrição</button_audiodescription>
  <div style="display:none" ; id="audiodescription-text">
    <p>
      [AUDIODESCRIÇÃO: representação tridimensional colorida de uma célula eucariótica seccionada, ou seja, cortada ao meio para mostrar as principais estruturas constituintes.<br><br> Para facilitar a compreensão e considerando a posição inicial em que
      o modelo tridimensional é carregado, a apresentação e a descrição das estruturas são feitas da esquerda para a direita e de fora para dentro, ou seja, as mais externas primeiro e em seguida as mais internas. Inicialmente são descritas as estruturas
      em primeiro plano, para depois serem descritas as estruturas em planos mais ao fundo.<br><br> A célula eucariótica apresenta formato irregular, mais próximo do arredondado, sendo delimitada pela membrana plasmática com superfície é lisa. Internamente,
      apresenta citoplasma e organelas.<br><br> Em uma célula real as organelas não possuem posição fixa, podendo variar de localização. Neste modelo tridimensional, em primeiro plano e à esquerda, encontram-se lisossomos, pequenas organelas de formato
      arredondado. Mais à direita está o Complexo de Golgi formado por sacos achatados e empilhados, interconectados por vesículas. Um pouco mais atrás, e à esquerda do lisossomo, encontra-se um endossomo, com formato arredondado similar aos lisossomos,
      porém de maior diâmetro. Segue-se o retículo endoplasmático rugoso, rede de cisternas e túbulos interconectados que possuem ribossomos aderidos à sua face externa, os quais estão representados como pequenos grânulos arredondados. À direita do retículo
      endoplasmático rugoso, está uma mitocôndria, de formato alongado e cilíndrico e com cristas mitocondriais de formato ondulado em seu interior. Logo atrás está um proteassomo, estrutura pequena, de formato cilíndrico, cujas extremidades apresentam
      projeções. Do lado direito do proteassomo está o retículo endoplasmático liso, formado por tubos alongados interconectados. Do lado direito do retículo endoplasmático liso está o núcleo, grande esfera com superfície lisa, dotada de poros circulares.
      O núcleo está seccionado de forma a mostrar, em sua região central, o nucléolo de formato também esférico. Finalmente, ao fundo, no extremo esquerdo, encontram-se dois centríolos de formato cilíndrico e dispostos perpendicularmente um ao outro,
      e no extremo direito, dois peroxissomos, organelas de formato circular semelhante ao endossomo e ao lisossomo.<br><br> FIM DA AUDIODESCRIÇÃO.]</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button_model id="button_model" onclick="showHidenButtonModel()">Exibir opções de cores</button_model>
<!-- Inserir aqui botão para exibir ou ocultar o menu de seleção de cores -->
<div style="display:none" ; id="options-wrapper">
  Altere aqui o estado inicial de exibição do menu de seleção de cores. display:none ocultará o elemento. display:inherit exibirá o elemento com os padrões de seu elemento-pai
  <div class="options" id="color-picker"></div>
</div>




I haven't looked at the rest of the code, I don't think it's relevant to this question.

I've added the HTML to my answer, you can see it works.

I think it's time for you to learn to use the debugger.

I tried merging my changes into your code, but it doesn't run because I don't have the Sketchfab libraries.

And it's time for you to be more appreciative of people helping you for free.

src="./assets/js/SketchfabConfigurator-1.0.6.js" refers to a file on your server. There's no way for me to load that without the full URL.
